# Bash script for user backups with BorgBackup

Tags: bash

I use [BorgBackup](https://www.borgbackup.org) to handle backups for my personal computer.
The following is a bash script that creates backups of my system to various different targets.
I have little experience with bash and hope to get some pointers regarding best practices and possible security issues/unanticipated edge cases.

One specific question is about the need to unset environment variables (in particular BORG_PASSPHRASE) like I have seen people doing (for example [here](https://blog.andrewkeech.com/posts/170719_borg.html))
From my understanding this should not be necessary because the environment is only local.

Ideally I would also like to automatically ensure the integrity of the Borg repositories. I know there is `borg check` which I could run from time to time, but I am not sure if this is even necessary when using `create` which supposedly already makes sure the repository is in a healthy state?

Some notes regarding the code below:

- `noti` is a very simple script for notifications with i3status but could be replaced with anything else
- Some paths and names are replaces with dummies
- I can not exit properly on errors of `borg create` because I backup /etc where some files have wrong permissions and BorgBackup will throw errors
- The TODO comments in the code are things I may want to look into at some time, but the code works for now

Bash script:

````bsh
#!/bin/bash

# User data backup script using BorgBackup with options for different target repositories
# usage: backup.sh <targetname>
# Each target must have a configuration file backup-<targetname>.conf that provides:
# - pre- and posthook functions
# - $repository - path to a valid borg repository or were one should be created
# - $backup - paths or exclusion paths
# - $pruning - borg pruning scheme
# Additional borg environment variables may be provided and will not be overwritten.
# Output is logged to LOGFILE="$HOME/.local/log/backup/<date>"

# INSTALLATION
# Place script and all target configs in $HOME/.local/scripts
# $HOME/.config/systemd/user/borg-backup.service
# ```
# [Unit]
# Description=Borg User Backup
# [Service]
# Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
# ExecStart=%h/.local/scripts/backup.sh target1
# Nice=19
# IOSchedulingClass=2
# IOSchedulingPriority=7
# ```
#
# $HOME/.config/systemd/user/borg-backup.timer
# ```
# [Unit]
# Description=Borg User Backup Timer
# [Timer]
# OnCalendar=*-*-* 8:00:00
# Persistent=true
# RandomizedDelaySec=10min
# WakeSystem=false
# [Install]
# WantedBy=timers.target
# ```
# $ systemctl --user import-environment PATH
# reload the daemon
# $ systemctl --user daemon-reload
# start the timer with
# $ systemctl --user start borg-backup.timer
# and confirm that it is running
# $ systemctl --user list-timer
# you can also run the service manually with
# $ systemctl --user start borg-backup


function error () {
    RED='\033[0;91m'
    NC='\033[0m'
    printf "${RED}%s${NC}\n" "${1}"
    notify-send -u critical "Borg" "Backup failed: ${1}"
    noti rm "BACKUP"
    noti add "BACKUP FAILED"
    exit 1
}


## Targets

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "$0: Missing arguments"
    echo "usage: $0 targetname"
    exit 1
fi

case "$1" in
    "target1"|"target2"|"target3")
        target="$1"
        ;;
    *)
        error "Unknown target"
        ;;
esac

# TODO abort if specified target is already running
# exit if borg is already running, maybe previous run didn't finish
#if pidof -x borg >/dev/null; then
#    error "Backup already running."
#fi


## Logging and notification

# notify about running backup
noti add "BACKUP"

# write output to logfile
log="$HOME/.local/log/backup/backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).log"
exec > >(tee -i "$log")
exec 2>&1

echo "$target"


## Global Prehook

# create list of installed software
pacman -Qeq > "$HOME/.local/log/package_list.txt"

# create list of non backed up resources
ls -R "$HOME/misc/" > "$HOME/.local/log/resources_list.txt"

# create list of music titles
ls -R "$HOME/music/" > "$HOME/music/music_list.txt"


## Global Config

# set repository passphrase
export BORG_PASSCOMMAND="cat $HOME/passwd.txt"

compression="lz4"


## Target specific Prehook and Config

CONFIGDIR="$HOME/.local/scripts"
source "$CONFIGDIR"/backup-"$target".conf

# TODO make non mandatory and only run if it is defined
prehook || error "prehook failed"


## Borg

# TODO use env variables in configs instead?
# export BORG_REPO=$1
# export BORG_REMOTE_PATH=borg1
# borg create ::'{hostname}-{utcnow:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S}' $HOME

SECONDS=0
echo "Begin of backup $(date)."

borg create                    \
    --verbose                  \
    --stats                    \
    --progress                 \
    --compression $compression \
    "$repository"::"{hostname}-{utcnow:%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S}" \
    $backup
#  || error "borg failed"

# use prune subcommand to maintain archives of this machine
borg prune                 \
    --verbose              \
    --list                 \
    --progress             \
    "$repository"          \
    --prefix "{hostname}-" \
    $pruning               \
  || error "prune failed"

echo "End of backup $(date). Duration: $SECONDS Seconds"


## Cleanup

posthook
noti rm "BACKUP"
echo "Finished"

exit 0
````

Example configuration file:

```bsh
backup="$HOME
--exclude $HOME/movie
--exclude $HOME/.cache
--exclude $HOME/.local/lib
--exclude $HOME/.thumbnails
--exclude $HOME/.Xauthority
"

pruning="--keep-daily=6 --keep-weekly=6 --keep-monthly=6"

repository="/run/media/username/DRIVE"

prehook() { :; }  # e.g. mount drives/network storage

posthook() { :; }  # unmount ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Your specific question

> One specific question is about the need to unset environment variables (in particular BORG_PASSPHRASE) like I have seen people doing (for example here) From my understanding this should not be necessary because the environment is only local.

When you execute a Bash script with `path/to/script.sh` or `bash path/to/script.sh`,
the script runs in a sub-shell, and cannot modify its caller environment.
No matter if the script has `export FOO=bar` or `unset FOO`,
these will not be visible in the caller shell.
So the example you linked to, having `BORG_PASSPHRASE=""` (and followed by `exit`) is completely pointless.

#### Use an array for `$backup`

This setup will break if ever `$HOME` contains whitespace:

> ```
> backup="$HOME
> --exclude $HOME/movie
> --exclude $HOME/.cache
> --exclude $HOME/.local/lib
> --exclude $HOME/.thumbnails
> --exclude $HOME/.Xauthority
> "
> ```

Even if that's unlikely to happen, it's easy enough and a good practice to make it safe,
by turning it into an array:

```
backup=(
    "$HOME"
    --exclude "$HOME/movie"
    --exclude "$HOME/.cache"
    --exclude "$HOME/.local/lib"
    --exclude "$HOME/.thumbnails"
    --exclude "$HOME/.Xauthority"
)
```

And then in the calling command:

```
borg create                    \
    --verbose                  \
    --stats                    \
    --progress                 \
    --compression $compression \
    "$repository"::"{hostname}-{utcnow:%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S}" \
    "${backup[@]}"
```

I suggest to do the same thing for `$pruning` too.
Although there is no risk there (with the current value) of something breaking,
it's a good practice to double-quote variables used on the command line.
So it should be:

```
pruning=(--keep-daily=6 --keep-weekly=6 --keep-monthly=6)
```

And then when using it: `"${pruning[@]}"`

#### Use stricter input validation

Looking at:

> ```
> if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
>     echo "$0: Missing arguments"
>     echo "usage: $0 targetname"
>     exit 1
> fi
> ```

According to the usage message,
only one argument is expected,
but the validation logic allows any number above that, and will simply ignore them.

I suggest to strengthen the condition:

```
if [ $# != 1 ]; then
```

#### Output error messages to `stderr`

The `error` function, and a few other places print error messages on `stdout`.
It's recommended to use `stderr` in these cases, for example:

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "$0: Missing arguments" >&2
    echo "usage: $0 targetname" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

#### Don't use SHOUT_CASE for variables

It's not recommended to use all caps variable names,
as these may clash with environment variables defined by system programs.

#### Use modern function declarations

The modern syntax doesn't use the function keyword, like this:

```
error() {
    # ...
}
```

#### Simplify `case` patterns

In this code:

> ```
> case "$1" in
>     "target1"|"target2"|"target3")
>         target="$1"
>         ;;
> ```

You can use glob patterns to simplify that expression:

```
case "$1" in
    "target"[1-3])
        target="$1"
        ;;
```

#### Why `exit 0` at the end?

The `exit 0` as the last statement is strange:
Bash will do the same thing automatically when reaching the end of the script.
You can safely remove it.

#### `SECONDS`

Wow, I completely forgot about this feature of Bash,
very cool, thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Unexporting environment variables may be a good practice here.  You rightly say that they are not visible to the parent process, but they are given to all _child_ processes, which we then have to trust not to expose them (e.g. in core dumps).  I would be inclined not to blindly `export` passwords like that, but to place them in the environments of just a few selected processes (e.g. by writing `BORG_PASSWORD="…" borg cmd …` or perhaps creating an alias for that).

Comment: Pedantically, the `exit 0` serves to mask any error status from the preceding `echo` command, since Bash actually returns the exit status of the last (non-trap) command.  But I don't think that was intentional!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>     RED='\033[0;91m'
>     NC='\033[0m'
>     printf "${RED}%s${NC}\n" "${1}"
> ```

Please don't hard-code terminal-specific escape sequences like that.  Standard output isn't necessarily a terminal, nor is it always the kind of terminal you're expecting.  I recommend you use appropriate `tput setaf` commands to generate the appropriate sequences for the actual output stream in use.  And shouldn't that message be going to the error stream, rather than the output stream?

---

I recommend `set -u` and probably also `set -e` to help avoid the common mistakes of continuing with unexpected state due to a typo or an unexpectedly failing command.

Comment: And everything that [janos wrote](/a/278984/75307), of course.